# "In Cell Phone" or "On Cell Phone"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Should I say "in cell phone" or "on cell phone"? Can you suggest to me which one to use? How about the mobile too, "in mobile" or "on mobile"? I'm always confused about it.

Answer (score 3):

You always call *on* phone and not *in.* On the other hand, you have memory *in* the phone where you store phone numbers, pictures etc. That is why, we call *built-in* memory and not *built-on* memory. We generally refer features of the phone as *in the phone* but call *on the phone*.

So, if you are concerned about telling someone to contact you, you say, *"Contact me **on** my phone."*

Comment: Thanks and my concern is what to tell if we are referring others to call another person.contact in his cell or on his cell?

Comment: Changing 'person' does not matter. Call on my/his/her phone/number.